# .htaccess rewrite file uri to either file-name.html or file-name.php - whichever exists

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

**OBJECTIVE:** To cause the browser to rewrite to file-name.php, if it exists; else return file-name.html - whether the visitor has typed the url as any one of the following:

1. `http://mydomain.com/file-name`
2. `http://mydomain.com/file-name.html`
3. `http://mydomain.com/file-name.php`

Had good success with the following rules in my .htaccess file at root:

```
# REWRITE FILE URI TO file.php IF EXISTS
Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
Options +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# parse out basename, but remember the fact
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1 [C,E=WasHTML:yes]
# rewrite to document.php if exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [S=1]
# else reverse the previous basename cutout
RewriteCond %{ENV:WasHTML} ^yes$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

However, I have since installed WP at root, alongside pre-existing website, and these rules are no longer working.

**WHAT DOES WORK:** `file-name` is rewritten to either `file-name.html` or `file-name.php` - whichever file exists.

**WHAT DOES NOT WORK:** `file-name.html` is not rewritten to `file-name.php` even when there is no `file-name.html` and `file-name.php` is there. Also, `file-name.php` is not rewritten to `file-name.html` when there is no `file-name.php` but there is `file-name.html`.

The entire .htaccess as it is now:

```
# BEGIN WP MULTISITE RULES
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WP MULTISITE RULES

# REWRITE FILE URI TO file.php IF EXISTS
Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
Options +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# parse out basename, but remember the fact
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1 [C,E=WasHTML:yes]
# rewrite to document.phtml if exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [S=1]
# else reverse the previous basename cutout
RewriteCond %{ENV:WasHTML} ^yes$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Any advices?

Comment: Yes, I moved the rules above WP, and it does work again. Mostly. That is, 'file-name' returns either 'file-name.html' or 'file-name.php' - whichever exists, and 'file-name.html' will return 'file-name.php' if it exists.But 'file-name.php' returns 404 if there is only a 'file-name.html' and no 'file-name.php'. What will cause rewrite of 'file-name.php' to 'file-name.html' in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Quick overview tells that your original rules most likely will never get reached as WP rules should intercept all requests.

This line `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` with those conditions will abort rewriting for any already existing files or folders, while this line `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` will intercept/redirect all requests to `index.php`.

If you move your rules above WordPress one, then it will work again.

---

To rewrite request for non-existing .php file to .html file use this rule:

```
# rewrite non-existing .php file to existing .html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1.html [L,PT]
```

Place it below your rules (but above WP). The rule will check if .php files does not exist and rewrite will only occurs if .html file is present. If both files are unavailable then nothing will happen.

Keep in mind that because of these checks and the fact that rule is on the top of rewrite chain, this rule will be evaluated for every request to .php file (even WP pages) which may put extra pressure on very busy server. Ideally you would like to have proper URLs in first place so there will be no need for such manipulations.

Comment: Thanks, @LazyOne. I tried placing your rules below mine and above WordPress rules, but 'file-name.php' still returns 404 when there is no 'file-name.php' but there is 'file-name.html'.

Comment: @user864464 I have tested the rule on my local Apache -- works absolutely fine. _Possibly_ some other rule affects it .. maybe your WP installation -- I cannot say for sure. The best thing -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log to see what is going on on your server (I cannot replicate your environment here). As I  said -- it works fine here .. but in injunction with other rules it may work differently considering the fact that your Apache set up can be completely different to mine.

Comment: @user864464 I have also tried your original rules + mine rule -- works fine again. It has to be something with WP rules .. or something _completely_ different (which I do not know what else it may be).

Comment: Why you used `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` instead of `{REQUEST_FILENAME}`? I substituted & tested, but still getting 404 when follow link to http://mydomain.com/subfolder/file-name.php, yet actual file is named 'file-name.html' (uri is http://mydomain.com/subfolder/file-name.html). When pre-exising website is phased out, these rules to be deleted so as to lighten the server load. : )

Comment: @user864464 Because I have duplicated second `RewriteCond` to make first and did not bother with changing anything -- the path will be the same anyway (in some rare cases (must be dues to Apache specific config) it even works better to assemble target file name using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` rather than use `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` directly). Remove WP rules completely (temporarily and test again). I recommend (if you can, of course) remove as much as you can and test if it works, then add other stuff and test again until you will see where it fails.

Comment: very sorry, but I tested on my local site also, without WordPress installation. Put your rules below mine. Not working. My setup MAMP 1.9.4, PHP 5.3.2. Anyway, it's after midnight here and my eyes are closing. Will look at it tomorrow. Thank you for your help. Have a good day|night!

Comment: Then I can only give these last advices: #1 Are you able to access that html file via Apache? Maybe it is a file permission issue. #2 Remove ALL rewrite rules from htaccess and all files -- you should have only 2 files on website: `.htaccess` and `file-name.html`. Add my rewrite rule ONLY and test (when testing make sure that file names and paths are correct). The lest files/rules around the more precise experiment is. The rule is 100% WORKING. If still nothing then #3 - enable rewrite debugging - that is your best option, which you CAN do since you have full control over local Apache server.